# Find if a string is present inside another string in Pig

Tags: string, apache-pig

I want to find if a string contains another string in Pig. I found that there is a built-in [`index`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#indexof) function, but it only searches for characters not strings.

Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this :

```
X = FILTER A BY (f1 matches '.*the_word_you're_looking_for.*');
```

More information here : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#comparison